# Method does not exist: updateUser(List<User>, Map<Id,User>, Map<Id,User>)

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written the below trigger handler logic but it throws a compile error.

**Error**

> IN operator must be used with an iterable expression

**Trigger**

```
  public with sharing class UsernameUpdateHandler {
    public void OnAfterUpdate(User[] oldUser, User[] updatedUser, Map<ID, User> oldUserMap, Map<ID, User> updatedUserMap){
        updateUser(updatedUserMap,oldUserMap);
    }

     public void updateUser(Map<ID,User>updatedUserMap,Map<ID, User> oldUserMap){

    if(TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun() || test.isRunningTest()){

      TriggerContextUtility.setFirstRunFalse();

      List<User> u = new List<User>(); 
      List<User> updateU = new List<User>(); 
      for (User o : [select id,Email,Username from User where (NOT Username LIKE '%portal%') AND (NOT Username LIKE '%chatter%') AND (NOT Username LIKE '%security%')AND (NOT Username LIKE '%integration%')AND (NOT Username LIKE'%dev%')AND (NOT Username LIKE'%fakeemail%')AND id IN: updatedUserMap]){
      if(oldUserMap.get(o.id).Email!= updatedUserMap.get(o.id).Email){
      o.Email= o.Username;
      u.add(o);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to conform to the method signature you have declared. It asks for `(List, Map)`, but you have provided `(List, Map, Map)`.

**Incorrect**

This method call will never compile as it does not conform to the signature you declared:

```
updateUser(updatedUser,oldUserMap,updatedUserMap);
```

**Correct**

This method call will compile, and ostensibly perform as you desire:

```
updateUser(updatedUser, oldUserMap);
// when you have defined this signature:
// public void updateUser(List<User> newRecords, Map<Id, User> oldMap){

// OR

updateUser(updatedUserMap, oldUserMap);
// when you have defined this signature:
// public void updateUser(Map<Id, User> newMap, Map<Id, User> oldMap){
```

---

Note that changing the signature in your method declaration broke the method implementation itself. You should just revert to your former implementation, as you have no need of a `Map` for the new records. If you insist on accepting both arguments as map, however, you can only iterate the new records by getting the `values` from the map:

**Incorrect**

```
for (User record : newMap)
```

**Correct**

```
for (User record : newMap.values())
```

Comment: I did try that..But still I have the same error..See the upated code

Comment: You changed the method signature...

Comment: I was able to fix the error, but was running into a different issue saying that it should be iterable. Can we specify the Map as ID'sList?

Comment: @user43146 If you're doing `IN :updatedUserMap`, you need to define if you're saying "look in the keys" or "look in the values". If your case you'd want to loop through the `keySet()`, specifically: `IN :updatedUserMap.keySet()`

Comment: Just revert to your original signature...

Comment: Error:  Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0055C000000Jj9VQAS; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): User, original object: Contact: []

Comment: @user43146 Please limit yourself to one question per question. If you have resolved the original issue here, consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. Then you can ask a new question around this entirely distinct error.

Comment: @user43146 I think you will find, however, that if you just do a bit of research on that error, you will find the answer yourself. When you ask questions on here without doing very basic research, you can find yourself accruing down-votes pretty quickly sometimes.